# Easy to config Exchange mail on Android but not Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, android, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2003, outlook-web-access

I have an Exchange account, in which I regularly access by OWA. I can easily config my android phone mail client to sync with this exchange email. However there's no way to config outlook 2010 (same for 2013) to sync with it.

How come 2 Microsoft products can't connect while Android can easily connect to the server without a hitch?

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Can I use Outlook 2010 (beta) with OWA account?](https://superuser.com/questions/72701/can-i-use-outlook-2010-beta-with-owa-account)

Short answer: android uses activesync while connecting outlook clients needs outlook anywhere enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple to connect outlook to it. In email accounts in outlook edit your account:

Click 'More Settings' In the general tab.

Click on the tab called 'connection'. Tick 'Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP'.

Click on 'Exchange Proxy Settings...'

The URL to connect to proxy server for Exchange is 'owa.***********.com'

20. Under Proxy authentication settings try changing this to:  'Basic Authentication'

Press OK