# Will Outlook 2016 connect to Exchange using EAS?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-10, exchange, activesync, microsoft-outlook-2016

[This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2859522) KB article acknowledges that Outlook *2013* won't connect to Exchange using EAS (Exchange ActiveSync) for non-Hotmail accounts, i.e., a corporate Exchange server.  There is also a similar six-year old [question](https://superuser.com/questions/43238/activesync-owa-desktop-client/450562) on the topic, as well as further discussion [here](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/exchange-eas-and-outlook-2013).

Has the situation changed any for Outlook *2016*?  The reason to ask is that the "free" Windows 10 mail client **does** support EAS connections (the same was true for Windows 8/8.1 too), so I would think Outlook would as well.  It seems rather odd that I should lose functionality when "upgrading" my Microsoft-provided email client.

(And, no, other options aren't possible, such as the much-preferred [Outlook Anywhere](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb123741(v=exchg.150).aspx) feature; the only supported "off site" configuration is EAS--for mobile devices.)

---

I'm trying to get Microsoft to weigh in: [Can't add non-Hotmail Exchange ActiveSync account in Outlook 2016](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-outlook/cant-add-non-hotmail-exchange-activesync-account/8aeadcda-2ad6-43ce-88d9-030d7ae28153?tm=1443032637597) .

Comment: I highly doubt Outlook 2016 will revert back to using EAS for direct Exchange connections.  The official answer is to tell your Exchange Admin to enable [Outlook Anywhere](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb123741(v=exchg.150).aspx). :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that just because Windows Mail App (a lesser client) works with EAS, that any other mail client should be able to do it. Outlook 2013 preview worked with EAS, and then when they released it they decided to remove support for it, as they didn't feel it offered enough for full Exchange/Outlook interoperability.  Also, if your Exchange admin won't enable it, ask him how you're supposed to use Outlook from home, perhaps they have alternative means they can provide you (ie: VPN into work network, or perhaps OWA).

Comment: And Microsoft's "Premier" Mail client expects it to have a "Premier" connection to Exchange, which EAS can't supply.  If you want Outlook to work from home with a corporate Exchange server, then you need to configure the Exchange server properly.  If you can't do that, then you're pretty much SOL.  But anyway, none of this has to do with your question which is "Will Outlook 2016 support EAS to an Exchange server", to which you've already received the answer.

Comment: Our expectations will not always align with reality. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Outlook 2016 supports EAS just like the Outlook 2013 does. But in a some weird way: you can connect to EAS servers that are **not** Exchange Server (like Outlook.com).

I believe this situation will change with the Exchange 2016 that introduces a new EAS protocol version.

Comment: Yep. This is what I said: it supports EAS servers other than Exchange. It looks like you're trying to connect to Exchange using EAS.

Comment: This problem stil not fixed in Outlook 2016. However It works well in Outlook 2013. Don't spend your time to configure this. or if you found a solution, please post your method.